# Is there a way to transfer properties from objects (and the scene) in one blend file to objects (& scene) in another blend file with the same names?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, export, import

I have a scene setup along with a series of scripts where I am exporting meshes and a armature as a fbx and then reimporting them into a new blender file.

Unfortunately when exporting a fbx, scene, mesh, empty and armature objects loose their blender specific object properties.

What I've been trying to do is have is a script that records the objects and scene settings to a external text file, then in the new blend file read that text file and set the properties of the objects with the same name from the previous file, (needs to include properties that are also from addons).

I don't want to copy the object's themselves, just their properties over to identically named objects in a new blend file.

[image: information that I'm looking to record]

If there is a better way to accomplish to do this them I'm all ears.

(The reason i'm doing this is because I'm building a animation pipeline that uses Auto rig pro's game ready exported rig, however to import final rig into the game, it needs additional blender settings so i'm reimporting the final rig into blender, setting the object settings and then sending that to the game)

This is something that I had that does write to a file for all the empties but I'm not sure how I can get blender to import the settings back into the file and I don't even know if what I'm doing is correct in the first place.

```
import bpy

# Get the relative directory path
relative_directory = bpy.path.abspath("//tmp/")

# Create a file path for the text file
file_path = relative_directory + "tmp_properties.txt"

# Collect all the empty objects in the scene
empty_objects = [obj for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects if obj.type == 'EMPTY']

# Open the file in write mode
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    # Write the object properties to the file
    for obj in empty_objects:
        file.write("Object Name: {}\n".format(obj.name))
        
        # Write all properties
        for key, value in obj.items():
            file.write("{}: {}\n".format(key, value))
        
        file.write("\n")

print("Object properties have been written to:", file_path)
```

writes a text file formatted like this for each object:

```
Object Name: #fx_display_light
nS: <bpy id prop: owner="OB#fx_display_light", name="nS", address=0x0000015A38C0F568>
als: <bpy id prop: owner="OB#fx_display_light", name="als", address=0x0000015A38C0F4C8>
nwo_face: <bpy id prop: owner="OB#fx_display_light", name="nwo_face", address=0x0000015A38C0F428>
nwo: <bpy id prop: owner="OB#fx_display_light", name="nwo", address=0x0000015A38C0F388>
```